# Execute a piece of code also when the cached version of a page is served

Tags: cache

How can I be sure that a piece of code is executed also for the cached page of the website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call it asynchronously via the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/).

In a best case scenario, you want the entire HTML of a page cached (full page cache). Executing PHP inside that is not easily possible and that's exactly the idea behind it

So what you want is some JavaScript that talks to the REST API. The JavaScript code (your "**logic**") must be written in a way that it does not need to change, so it can be embedded within the cached HTML. Your **data** that comes from the endpoint can change, because the endpoint is not cached in the same way as a site is.

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to ask also: if the cache is done through a PHP Plugin, is there any place where I have good chance that Wordpress will execute the PHP code?

Comment: @Revious That heavily relies on the plugin. I know W3TC offers so called "fragment caching" which is what you're looking for. But I never used it nor do I know if and how other plugins do. As I said: executing part of a cached page is a very tricky thing. In my experience, going the asynchronous JS way is the best solution. As long as it is loaded relatively quickly, it shouldn't be a problem for SEO either.